# Training modern object detection with Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection-api

The Tensorflow [object detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) is deprecated, and refers to [Tensorflow-vision.](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official/vision) Unfortunately, the documentation, as far as I can see, is just links to a series of preprints. All the other [references](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/examples/object_detection/overview) go back to the deprecated API.

So, how can I train an object detection model with Tensorflow in 2023?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the functionality has been moved to [Keras CV.](https://keras.io/keras_cv/) The examples are [here.](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-cv/tree/master/examples/training/object_detection)